# Define a directed edge in a DAG using partial ordering

Tags: graph-theory, order-theory

I am trying to describe a novel type of DAG's construction algorithm (in computer science). The directed edges of the graph correspond to a partial ordering: i.e. any directed edge $e$ spanning from $f$ to $t$ also observes: $f \preceq t$.

Q: How can I precisely define the main task of edge construction: that is finding the node $f$ for a given $t$?

It is something like this:

find all $f_a \in \{ f_i \}$ s.t. $f_a \preceq t$
$\land \nexists f_j$ s.t. $f_i \preceq f_j$

but I'm not sure if this is sufficient or even understandable?

Comment: Like a Hasse diagram of the poset? you want the notion of covering? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_relation

Comment: The graph is a DAG where the edges are added according to a partial ordering of the nodes. It is not the goal to try to visualize the partial ordering using a pre-defined diagram. Maybe I should ask on the `cs` stackexchange instead :/

Comment: Hum... What I mean is that the graph that I'm triyng to build is my own invention and does not follow the rules of, lets say the Hasse diagram. Also, its directed edges encapsulate a partial ordering. But I guess that can be said about any graph...? Maybe I'm just overcomplicating it by trying to use a partial order to define the graph...

Comment: Well, just give us an example, so we know what you are doing. The statement that you have is a little vague and, perhaps, we can help to formalize it.

Comment: @Phicar thank you for the encouragement. Without getting too specific: the DAG itself is that of an executed program, and is used for dynamic runtime analysis. Each node represents the execution of some event, while an edge $e = f \rightarrow t$ means that $f$ follows $t$ according to some rule set.
But I know that this is still too vague. I am currently re-thinking my wording and how to summarize said "rule set" in a few clear statements.

Comment: Ok, sounds like a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_graph to me. Please edit the question when you can give us the "rule set".

Comment: @Phicar Thanks! I shall try!

Comment: It's also worth noting that the task "precisely define X" is not at all the same as "express X in terms of many symbols like $\exists$, $\land$, $\neg$, $\iff$ and no words".

Comment: @MishaLavrov I agree. I also came to the conclusion that a short, concise "wordy" version might be more useful than an attempt at pseudo symbolism, or so I think... I will see as I draw up a concept graph etc. A few picture and examples can probably also aid the definition... Or so I hope